# Parse string column to boolean while reading it?

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I've got a huge CSV file with a string-type column

example:

```
...  string_column
...  f
...  f
...  t
...  f
...  t
...  f
```

I am looking to parse the string colum to boolean values while reading the csv. Changing the dataframe after like below is not possible due to RAM limits.

```
df = pd.read_csv(tmpfile)
df['string_column'] = np.where(df.type=='t',-1,1)
```

How could I achieve this?

```
pd.read_csv(tmpfile,dtype={'string_column': np.bool})
```

doesn't work obviously.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify what values should be replaced to `True` and `False` in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

```
df = pd.read_csv("path", true_values=['t'], false_values=['f'])
```